# Removing space between h1 and h2

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I have stumbled across a problem that I can not seem to solve in any way, maybe I am using `div`s in a wrong way?

```css
.greeting h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center
}
.greeting h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="greeting">
  <h1>Hi.</h1>
  <h2>Select a group</h2>
</div>
```

This is the outcome:

[image: SS]

I want to decrease the space between my `<h1>` and `<h2>`, and I found out that the way to do that was to set `line-height` in `h1` to `0px`.

But as I do that my entire page moves up like so:

[image: SS]

I want to keep the text at the same position as it was before I change the `line-height`. I am suspecting that I am using the div class function wrong. This is more of theoretical question.

Answer (score 20):

headings `h1` to `h6` have `margin` by default, so you need to reset it, setting: `margin:0`.

```css
.greeting h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0
}
.greeting h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="greeting">
  <h1>Hi.</h1>
  <h2>Select a group</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

HTML heading tags have some default CSS values applied in most browsers. Following are the values of `h1` and `h2` that are applied to them by default, so you need to override the `margin-bottom` of `h1` and `margin-top` of `h2` if you want to decrease the spacing between your `h1` and `h2`.

```
h1 { 
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0.83em;
  margin-bottom: 0.83em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```css
.greeting h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.greeting h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="greeting">
  <h1>Hi.</h1>
  <h2>Select a group</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following lines

```
.greeting h1 {
  margin:0px;
  line-height:35px;
}
.greeting h2 {
  margin:0px;
  line-height:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want you to assign the margin only for this block you do not need to define it globally you can just do the same this using inline CSS

```
<h1  style="margin-bottom: 0">Hi</h1>
<h2  style="margin-top: 0">Select a group</h2>
```